# how to type multitple lines input in java console (mac)

Tags: java, terminal, command

I am writing an small algorithm program which takes multiple lines user input (System.in).
my question is how to type the multiple line input ?
all questions on internet are about how to read multiple lines input. seems i am the only one having this kinda problem.
For example, here is the simple program that reads input line by line and print the input every time.

```
public class yahoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

my question is , how to type , say , two lines of input at one line in the java console (the terminal).
I mean I want to type :

```
first line
second line
```

as input at one time.

Then expect the output be:

```
first line 
second line
```

instead of something like

```
first line
first line
second line 
second line
```

[vscode picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H45QE.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean "how to type the multiple line input"? Type some character, then press enter, then more characters, then enter again and so on...

Comment: About your edit, instead of printing immediately put your strings inside a list, then when you're done getting inputs traverse the list and print its contents one line element at a time.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question as text. I'd love to see how it works on my system, but I'm not willing to type it in just to see.

Comment: Yes , I know that could solve my problem. But I am interested in how to type multiple lines input on terminal  without changing the code.  Every time I hit enter , console  print  then force me to write the next line input.

Comment: @KiraYagami You can't expect your code to behave differently without changing it. What your code is saying is "while there are lines, read a line then print it". So that's exactly what it does.